Define default payment method per account on aws
There's documentation on aws about how to set the default payment method for an account here.
In my case, I have a organization with non-consolidated billing (several companies sharing an aws console).
I would like to set a default payment method per organization, is that possible? I haven't been able to find a solution.

You might get a better response at: https://repost.aws/
